# What can I put as my watir-webdriver page "element" in a condition where it's not there?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'm testing a nightmarish website that in most situations sticks all the important stuff in an iframe.

However, there are other common situations where the system will, annoyingly, open a page in a new tab, but not wrapped in the iframe.

I'm trying to figure out a conditional method that will check for the existence of the iframe and use it, otherwise not.

Here's what I've come up with, so far:

```
# The browser object...
@br = Watir::Browser.new
```

"frm" is the conditional method I'm trying to get working...

```
# Just an example element definition...
def click_my_button
  @br.frm.button(id: "button").click
end
```

I define it in Watir's Container module, like so:

```
module Watir
  module Container
    def frm
      if frame(id: "iframeportlet").exist?
        frame(id: "iframeportlet")
      else
        # This is the part that I can't figure out.
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That works fine when the iframe is there, but not surprisingly I get a NilClass error when it's not.

So, my question is: what can go into the else clause to make it work?  More broadly, is there perhaps a better way to accomplish this? As you can imagine, I really want to avoid having to define every element in the web site twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and it's quite simple. The frm method's else clause just needs a "self"...

```
else
  self
end
```

That's it.  I'd love to know if there are any hidden pitfalls with this approach, though.